# What property sheet can be used by the solution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, propertysheet

I'm debugging a existing codes for my company. They are built by some third party building tool. We use Microsoft Visual Studio to view/edit the source code. The source codes are in hundreds of projects files (.vcxproj) and some are not in any of projects. Among them there are codes like following:

```
#if ENABLE_XXX
    ....
#endif
```

The macro `ENABLE_XXX` would be defined somewhere in the build chain but could not be solved by Visual Studio. So currently the related part of codes are grayed out in the IDE. And no intelligence were generated for them. I'm thinking of defining such macro in a property sheet file so that I can enjoy the features provided by VS. I know how to do so for each project but wonder if there is any easy way to do that in solution level?
Thanks.

Comment: That's not possible.  Changing settings for multiple projects is possible by selecting them all first.